# THREE.js Uncaught TypeError dependant on three.js version i'm importing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I initially started my three.js project using version 0.118.0, and have imported three.js, as well as relevant addons as seen below.

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.0/build/three.module.js';

import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
```

I have no issues doing this, however when i try and use a newer version, for example 0.148.0, i get the TypeError seen below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I have ensured that the paths to the add-ons are updated depending on the version however the problem still persists, any idea what could be the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define an import map since `three.js` addons use the `three` bare module specifier since `r137`. The import map has this structure:

```
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.148/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@.0148/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
```

And in your JS, you import files like so:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

More details about this in the official [Installation guide](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation).

In any event, imports are now unified. That means it does not matter whether you import files in a node environment or directly in the browser. The import syntax is equal.